# How do I find out entry-point function in C++ dll project?

Tags: c++, dll, entry-point

I built one project from GitHub. The project was built successfully, but I can't find the entry-point function in its code. The project settings are like this:

[image]

How do I find out the entry-point function in a C++ DLL project?

Comment: You don't need it actually. Trust me.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. Often dlls don't have an entry point, and even when they do, it does not contain any user-written code. So you should specify what do you need it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [/ENTRY (Entry-Point Symbol)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-170):

> By default, the starting address is a function name from the C run-time library. The linker selects it according to the attributes of the program...

Unless specified differently, the entry point for a DLL in a MSVC++ project is `_DllMainCRTStartup()`, which calls `DllMain()` in the project's code, if it exists.

See [DLLs and Visual C++ run-time library behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior?view=msvc-170) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I can't find _DllMainCRTStartup() or DllMain() function in the project's code. But I need to customize the entry-point function for my working project. I am using VS2019....

Comment: @CM-1207 did you even read the documentation I linked to? `_DllMainCRTStartup()` is implemented by the C runtime library that is linked into the project, not implemented by the project itself. And `DllMain()` is *optional* in the project. If it doesn't already exist in the project's code, you can simply add it. You don't need to set the project's `Entry Point` configuration, unless you want to use a separate function that has a different name. But you rarely ever need to do that, just stick with the default `DllMain()`